# Matrix Big O Notation

Tags: matrix, big-o

I have a problem in calculating the Big O Notation for the code below...I know that hadn't the size of the matrix been known it would be O(n^3), but since this is a 16 x 16 matrix (i.e. the size is known) does it make it O(1)?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 16
int main()
{
        float matrix1 [SIZE][SIZE];
        float matrix2 [SIZE][SIZE];
        float result  [SIZE][SIZE];

        srand(time(NULL));
        int s,j,k=0;

        //Generating and displaying matrix 1
        printf("Matrix 1\n");

        for(s=0; s<SIZE;s++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<SIZE;j++)
            {
                matrix1[s][j] = ((float)rand()/RAND_MAX)*10;
                printf("%.3f\t" ,matrix1[s][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

       //Generating and displaying matrix 2
       printf("\n\nMatrix 2\n");

       for(s=0; s<SIZE;s++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<SIZE;j++)
            {
                matrix2[s][j] = ((float)rand()/RAND_MAX)*10;
                 printf("%.3f\t" ,matrix2[s][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

        //Generating and displaying Result Matrix
        printf("\n\nResult Matrix\n");

        for(s=0;s<SIZE;s++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<SIZE;j++)
            {
                float sum=0.0;
                for(k=0;k<SIZE;k++)
                {
                    sum=sum+(matrix1[s][k]*matrix2[k][j]);
                }
                result[s][j]=sum;
                printf("%.3f\t" ,result[s][j]);
            }

            printf("\n");
        }

    fflush(stdin);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's O(1), but with a *huge* constant being hidden by the big-oh notation, and can only be meaningfully compared to other algorithms for multiplying 16x16 matrices.

Comment: You hardly have to care about Big-O notation if size is known beforehand, fixed and negligible

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was in doubt as I need to mention it in my School Project. Thanks once again !

Answer (score 1):

Time complexity is the time taken by an algorithm to run as a function of the length of the string representing the input

The length of the matrix given = SIZE * SIZE * SIZE.

So the time complexity = O(SIZE * SIZE * SIZE) (assume SIZE = n)

Time complexity is O(n^3).

The problem here is that SIZE is predefined. Hence it becomes a constant

We eliminate constants for taking Big-Oh notations. Hence the time complexity will be T(n) = C^3 = O(1) (where C is a constant)